# What event is fired when a datagridview column is automatically sorted?

Tags: c#, sorting, events, datagridview, datagrid

I have the following code that highlights a cell when the user makes changes.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedRow = e.RowIndex;
        int selectedCol = e.ColumnIndex;

        if (selectedRow >= 0 && selectedCol >=0 )
        {
            dataGridView1[selectedCol, selectedRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
```

The user can sort a column prior to updating the cell. The data looks like this (note the price column is sorted in ascending order ) before updating:

[image]

I changed $40.98 to $45. The datagrid automatically sorts itself. The cell that is highlighted is where the updated call was located originally. The new cell that contains $45 is not highlighted.

Datagrid after the update and automatic sorting:

[image]

The datagrid's Sorted event is not fired during the automatic sorting process. Could anybody please show me show to fix the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `ListChanged` (type  `ItemMoved`) event is fired

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and I use this way:

I have declared a private variable in the class of the form:

```
private string id = string.Empty;
```

then my CellValueChanged method

```
private void dgvOggetto_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
// other code

            ID = dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
        }
```

and I used the SelectionChanged method

```
private void dgvOggetto_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// avoid fire the event if the Tag contains a keyword
            if (dataGridView.Tag.ToString().Contains("updating")) return;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ID))
            {
//find the row
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView.Rows
                    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString().Equals(id));

                if (row != null)
                {
//select the row 
                    dataGridView.Rows[row.Index].Selected = true;
                    dataGridView.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Selected = true;

                    // place the current row in the middle
                    dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = (row.Index - (dataGridView.Height - dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight) / dataGridView.RowTemplate.Height / 2) > 0 ? row.Index - (dataGridView.Height - dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight) / dataGridView.RowTemplate.Height / 2 : 0;
                }

// clean ID variable
                ID = string.Empty;
            }
        }
```